# Unauthorized Access not redirected with AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented `CustomAuthorization` overriding `AuthorizeAttribute`.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        var isUserExist = false;

        if (isAuthorized)
        {
    //To check if user exists in DB     
        }

        return isAuthorized && isUserExist;
    }
}
```

This is working fine, when the user is not authorized, it is displaying `401` unauthorized error. 
But on this case I want to redirect it to the `Custom Unauthorized Page`. For this I have added the below in `web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Home/Unauthorized" />
</customErrors>
```

In my controller,

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
        return View(ActionMethods.HOME_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

My issue is, it is not redirecting to the custom page instead it is prompting for Username/password browser popup.

Sharing ideas/experiences will be better.

**Update from Comments:**

I am using `Windows Authentication` and in `IIS` Enabled both `Windows Authentication` and `Anonymous Authentication`.

Comment: Is the prompt for username/password a dialog window or a page in your application?

Comment: @WillRay a dialog window of browser

Comment: I believe that's the default behavior of the base class.  I.e. if you are not logged in, attempt to give the user a chance to authenticate themselves.  If, after having a valid login, they still are unauthorized, then we redirect to the unauthorized page.

Comment: Something you may want to do is to set up a separate ErrorController and move all your error states there.  ErrorController will not have the `[Authorize]` attribute, so there should be no confusion when hitting one of those pages.  The URL would look like: `http://www.myawesomeapp.com/Error/Unauthorized`

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, Still not working after moving to separate controller

Comment: I think you are using windows based authentication, in that case check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087755/use-anonymous-authentication-in-mvc4-on-single-controller-when-the-whole-applica), it has a solution that you can use.

Comment: @SamGhatak, Yes Windows Authentication only

Comment: @SamGhatak, That solution doesn't work for me as I am using `Custom Authorize Attribute`

Comment: @SSS Is your IIS configured to do windows authentication, and deny anonymous authentication? IIS settings come into play before MVC is reached, so if anonymous authentication is not allowed it will never make it to your code anyways.

Comment: @WillRay, Yes it was disabled, but now I enabled `Anonymous Authentication` but still not working

Comment: I would give [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6101794/4270650) a try.

Comment: @WillRay, Still not working...